# ASP.NET CORE MVC Route: trying to pass a dictionary in asp-all-route-data

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I have an Object that I'm trying to pass to another route.

**In my index.cshtml I am creating the dictionary object i want to send:**

```
                    @{
                        var data = new Dictionary<string , ProductToCart>
                        {
                            {"item",  Model }
                         };
                    }
```

I have also link tag (in this view) with the asp-all-route-data to pass my dictionary to as follows:

```
  <a asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route="productData" asp-all-route-data="data" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary text-uppercase"> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart </a>
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
> eComStore.Models.ProductToCart>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>'. An explicit
> conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

**Q: How can I convert this dictionary and it is the correct way to pass a dictionary/complex object via route in ASP.NET CORE MVC?**

Comment: Hi @Shaz, any updates about this case? Have you resolved the issue with the solution we shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, eComStore.Models.ProductToCart>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>'.

If you check [the source code of `AnchorTagHelper`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f5b6039add50ea84ddb151cd6daf5207119dc116/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/AnchorTagHelper.cs#L138), you would find that `RouteValues` is defined as `IDictionary<string, string>`, as below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Additional parameters for the route.
/// </summary>
[HtmlAttributeName(RouteValuesDictionaryName, DictionaryAttributePrefix = RouteValuesPrefix)]
public IDictionary<string, string> RouteValues
{
    get
    {
        if (_routeValues == null)
        {
            _routeValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        return _routeValues;
    }
    set
    {
        _routeValues = value;
    }
}
```

If you'd like to pass complex object via route, you can try to serialize it as json string.

```
@{

    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    data.Add("item", ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString)Json.Serialize(Model)).Value);
}

<a asp-route="productData" asp-all-route-data="data"  class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary text-uppercase"> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart </a>
```

Please note that it might exceed maximum length limitation of the query string if the object is too complex.

Besides, as @DA mentioned, another approach of achieving the requirement is implementing a custom AnchorTagHelper.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working with complex types in the default way.
You should create your own custom tag helper.

This [article](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/01/mvc-6-anchor-tag-helper.aspx) may help you to understand more about tag helpers and [here](https://www.fortech.ro/taghelpers-asp-net-core-mvc/) on how to create your own custom tag helper.